# JSONPath unable to parse when expression contains hyphen

Tags: php, json, testing, codeception, jsonpath

I am using codeception for testing my JSON API laravel project. I am using codeception's JSONPath functions to check the structure of the responses. I am unable to parse the expression when it contains a hyphen. Json Path uses hyphen as a subtraction operator, but in this case I have used it as a string. I know putting the substring containing hyohen inside double quotes("") inside the whole expression in single quote should do that. but its not working.

here is the function on my api test suite SomeTestCest.php

```
public function someTest(ApiTester $I)
{
    $I->sendGET('/teachers/122');
    //used double quotes as it contains hyphen
    $I->seeResponseJsonMatchesJsonPath('$.data.[*].relationships."high-schools"');
}
```

here is a sample response from the get request in the test.

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "teachers",
        "id": "122",
        "attributes": {
            "fullname": "Rhoda Frami",
        },
        "relationships": {
            "high-schools": {
                "data": null
            },
            "subjects": {
                "data": null
            }
        },
        "links": {
            "self": "http:\/\/api.project:81\/teachers\/122"
        }
    }
}
```

when i run the tests using following

```
php codecept run tests/api/resources/SomeTestCest.php --steps --verbose
```

it throws an error

```
There was 1 failure:

---------
1) SomeTestCest:
 Test  tests/api/resources/SomeTestCest.php:someTest
 Step  See response json matches json path "$.data.[*].relationships."high-schools""
 Fail  Received JSON did not match the JsonPath `$.data.[*].relationships."high-schools"`.
Json Response: 
    {
    "data": {
        "type": "teachers",
        "id": "122",
        "attributes": {
            "fullname": "Rhoda Frami",
        },
        "relationships": {
            "high-schools": {
                "data": null
            },
            "subjects": {
                "data": null
            }
        },
        "links": {
            "self": "http:\/\/api.project:81\/teachers\/122"
        }
    }
}
```

i have tried following ways as well

```
$I->seeResponseJsonMatchesJsonPath("$.data.[*].relationships.'high-schools'");

$I->seeResponseJsonMatchesJsonPath('$.data.[*].relationships."high-schools"');

$I->seeResponseJsonMatchesJsonPath('$.data.[*].relationships.high-schools');

$I->seeResponseJsonMatchesJsonPath("$.data.[*].relationships.high-schools");
```

and its either this error. I know its because the hyphen is not parsed as its intended.

```
There was 1 error:

---------
1) SomeTestCest: 
 Test  tests/api/resources/SomeTestCest.php:SomeTest

  [Flow\JSONPath\JSONPathException] Unable to parse token high-schools in expression: .data.[*].relationships.high-schools
```

So i checked with the base package [JSONPath](https://github.com/FlowCommunications/JSONPath) that is being used by codeception and found that it was working as intended.

```
$data = ['people' => [['high-schools' => 'Joe'], ['high-schools' => 'Jane'], ['high-schools' => 'John']]];
$result = (new \Flow\JSONPath\JSONPath($data))->find('$.people.*."high-schools"');
print_r($result);
```

here is the result

```
Flow\JSONPath\JSONPath Object
(
    [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Joe
            [1] => Jane
            [2] => John
        )

    [options:protected] => 0
)
=> true
```

So my question is how to parse a json string that contains a hyphen(-) to check the structure of json using Codeception with Json Path?

Thank you

Comment: The actual difference between working and non-working examples is that you have unnecessary `.[*]` part in non-working example. Try to use `'$.data.relationships."high-schools"'`